Space of all Absolutely Continuous Measures
My professor recently asked the following question

If $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is a measureable space and $M_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ be the space of all $\mathbb{k}$-valued measures on $\mathcal{A}$, and $AC_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ is the space of all absolutely continuous measures (w.r.t a positive measure $\mu$) on $\mathcal{A}$, then is $AC_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ a Banach space?

I really don't know how to go about this problem. My thought process:

Let, $\{\nu_{n}\}\subseteq AC_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ be a sequence such that $\nu_{n}\to\nu$ in $M_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ and $\nu_{n}<<\mu$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, $||\nu_{n}-\nu||<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Then, $|\nu_{n}-\nu|(E)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and $E\in\mathcal{A}$.

Now, I can't seem to proceed after this. Any help?

With respect to which norm? Based off of your work so far, I assume total variation norm?

@BBBBBB yes it is the total variation norm

What is $\mathbb k$?

Either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Under the additional assumption that  $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, the map $f \mapsto f \cdot \mu$ is an isomorphism of norm spaces from $L^1(\mu)$ to $AC_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ by Radon-Nikodym's theorem. Hence $AC_{\mathbb{k}}(X)$ is a Banach space since $L^1(\mu)$ is.

@ChristopheLeuridan learned about the Radon-Nikodym theorem today itself. I guess this would be a good warm-up to get used to the result. Thanks!

It is enough to show that for a sequence of measures $\{\mu_k\} \subset AC_{\mathbb k}(X)$, if
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|\mu_k\| < \infty,$$
the measure
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_k$$ is well-defined (the series converges in $M_{\mathbb k}(X)$) and belongs to $AC_{\mathbb k}(X)$.
That
$$\sum_k \mu_k(E) \in \mathbb k$$
for each measurable set $E$ follows from completeness of $\mathbb k$. Countable additivity follows by Fubini's theorem.
Further, if $E$ is a set such that $\mu(E) = 0$, then since $\mu_k \ll \mu$ we have $\mu_k(E) = 0$ for all $k$, whence
$$\sum_k \mu_k(E) = 0,$$
so that $\sum \mu_k \ll \mu$. Thus $\sum \mu_k \in AC_{\mathbb k}(X)$.

Are we using the result that X is a Banach Space $\iff$ absolutely convergent is convergent?

Yes, that is the result.

Thanks! This is an amazing way. Beautiful!

Yes, the implication $\Leftarrow$ is used here.
